# Reverse Proxy of SugarCRM PHP on IIS

Tags: php, cross-domain, sugarcrm

I know nothing about PHP or SugarCRM yet I've had both thrown at me and the task of reverse proxying an instance of SugarCRM running on IIS.

I have a reverse proxy setup using ARR and URL rewrite on IIS which forwards requests to the SugarCRM instance.

A call would be as follows:

sugarproxy/sugarcrm => proxy => sugarserver/sugarcrm

I'm hoping for the home/login page to be returned but I always get a permanent redirect to sugarserver/sugarcrm/.

I'm suspecting this is PHP not allowing a request where the host/referrer doesn't match sugarserver. But I'm not sure.

How would I set the PHP config to allow sugarproxy as a valid host/referrer? Or if this isn't the problem how else would I solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this, in a way.

SugarCRM was redirecting to a url with a trailing slash, which I missed.

Now I'm letting it doe that and using URL Rewrite/ARR to rewrite the redirect to sugarproxy/sugarcrm/ and letting the proxy do it's things. It all seems OK now.